# How can I play a FLV file in a C++ OpenGL application?

Tags: c++, flash, opengl, flv

I am trying to play a .flv file in the GLUT window using OpenGL and C++ in Linux, but I'm not sure where to start.

Is it possible to do this?  If so, how?

Comment: Ogre 3D engine have plugins that can play flash video. That can be your starting point.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you mean [.flv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLV) not [.swf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWF).

It's quite easy. Decode the video with something like [libavcodec](http://www.inb.uni-luebeck.de/~boehme/using_libavcodec.html) and you can use raw frames as textures.

Comment: Oh, you are right, the OP meant flash *VIDEO* apparently. That can be done.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this, check out the source code of Gnash. They've a renderer that use OpenGL. However, rendering is just a small part of the job, you also have to decode audio/video, run actionscript, etc.. in order to run a flash file.

It so complicated that even Adobe didn't manage to make it right :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play just some video, look at @Banthar's answer, otherwise:

---

OpenGL is a no-frills drawing API. It gives you the computer equivalent of "pens and brushes" to draw on some framebuffer. Period. No higher level functionality than that.

Flash it a really complex thing. It consists of a vector geometry object system, a script engine (ActionScript), provides sound and video de-/compression etc. All this must be supported by a SWF player. ATM there's only one fully featured SWF player and that's the one Adobe makes. There are free alternatives, but the are behind the official flash players by several major versions (Lightspark, Gnash).

So the most viable thing to do was loading the Flash player browser plugin in your program through the plugin interface, provide it, what a browser provided to a plugin (DOM, HTTP transport, etc.) and have the plugin render to a offscreen buffer which you then copy to OpenGL context. But that's not very efficient.

TL;DR: Complicated as sh**, and probably not worth the effort.